# Как правильно сделать GET-запрос внутри теста Flask?

Tags: python, flask, get, юнит-тесты, python-unittest

Есть фласк-эндпоинт, запускающий сервер дочерним процессом.

```
@app.route("/start_server", methods=["POST"])
def start_server():
    form_data = request.get_data(as_text=True)

    try:
        data_object = json.loads(form_data)
    except JSONDecodeError as err:
        return "Invalid data. " + str(err), 400

    server_path = data_object['server_path']
    port = data_object['port']
    timeout = data_object['timeout']
    output_path = data_object['output_path']

    with open(output_path, 'w') as log:
        command = f'python {server_path} {port}'
        command_list = shlex.split(command)
        server_process = subprocess.Popen(command_list, stdout=log, stderr=log)
        time.sleep(timeout)
        server_process.kill()

    return 'Success'
```

К нему необходимо написать тест.

```
class StartServerTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        app.config['DEBUG'] = False
        app.config["WTF_CSRF_ENABLED"] = False
        self.app = app.test_client()
        self.base_url = '/start_server'

    def start_server_thread(self, post_data):
        self.app.post(self.base_url, data=post_data)

    def test_server_success(self):
        data = {
            'server_path': 'server.py',
            'port': 4000,
            'timeout': 5,
            'output_path': 'output.txt',
        }
        post_data = json.dumps(data)
        start_server = threading.Thread(target=self.start_server_thread, args=(post_data,))
        start_server.start()
        requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:4000/')
        start_server.join()

        with open('output.txt') as file:
            output = file.read()
            self.assertTrue('GET / HTTP/1.1" 200' in output)
```

Проблема в том, что запрос внутри теста не работает. Я пробовал делать его как в параллельных потоках, так и просто следом за запуском сервера. В результате всегда выбрасывается одна и та же ошибка.
`urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема разрешена.
Достаточно было сделать паузу перед запросом

```
start_server.start()
time.sleep(1)
requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:4000/')
start_server.join()
```